# Is it possible to get facebook friends via Live SDK?

Tags: windows-live

I can connect my Facebook acount to Windows Live. After that, all my fb friends are imported into Live and I can see them as my contacts. 
Is it possible to get them somehow using Live SDK? Requesting /me/friends returns only "native" live contacts.